What is the right way to calculate EER metric (speaker verification)?
I have a speaker verification model which I want to measure its performance using EER metric.
I have X speakers and each speaker has multiple speech files.
I'm calculating EER in the following way:

I'm calculating cosine similarity between all the pairs (between all the speech files and all the speakers).
Now  I'm calculating the roc curve and take the FNR and FPR and calculate the EER.

In this way - I have more (much more) pairs of negative labels (not the same speaker)
i.e:
If I have 10 speakers and each speaker has 10 files:
for one file from speaker X we have 9 positive labels and 90 negative labels.

Is the way I'm calculating EER right?
Does my way lead to imbalance pairs ?

